# How does one remove the annoying "One account for everything" Sign in under Accounts section

Tags: windows-11, user-accounts

This is a Windows 11 Professional 22H2 Build 22621.2283 machine, un-modified.

I don't want users to be able to sign in to a Microsoft account and wish to remove all options and annoying options like the one in the picture below.

I've already done the following and re-booted in between:

gpedit.msc -> "Accounts: Block Microsoft accounts" set to "Users can't add or logon with Microsoft accounts"

regedit32.exe ->"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Policies\System value set to 0 (zero)

I've attached a picture for clarity:

[image: Annoying MS Prompt]

Any help removing this would be greatly appreciated, am I just missing something?

Comment: Windows 11 (and 10) allow you to freely create a Local Account or a Microsoft Account.  But so far are I know, it cannot natively remove the ability to create a Microsoft Account. Since any account is just a Windows User Profile, what is the issue?

Comment: Are the accounts you're using Microsoft accounts, or local domain only? Are the computers enrolled in a domain?

Comment: While you can avoid linking a local account to a Microsoft Account you will be unable to avoid the prompts to do so, so what you want strictly speaking, is impossible on Windows 11. You should clarify what “this” is exactly for future users.

Comment: Thank you Ramhound a clear a precise answer. Many thanks